# Efficient custom input components in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection

In our angular application we expect to have a high number of input fields per form. We have implemented custom input components, each responsible for handling one input field and showing the corresponding error messages using reactive forms.
While we are aware of the possibility to divide form-groups into smaller groups and arrays we would like to have an efficient solution for the smallest parts of the form.
I would like to ask, if there is a better (as in render time and less unnecessary change detection) way to achive our goal compared to our solution demonstrated below.
Current solution:
The custom input components have an @Input String specifying the formControlName to bind the Form Control to the Input with the help of using the existing FormGroupDirective via viewProvider.
In the custom component we also have "@ViewChild(FormControlName) control" which binds to the FormControl and is used to check for validity and error output if necessary.
A minimal Example would be:
parent.component.ts :

```
exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    exampleControl1: [null,Validators.required],
    exampleControl2: [null,Validators.required]});
```

parent.component.html :

```
<form [formGroup]="patientForm">
<app-inputtype1-component>Label-String 1</app-inputtype1-component>
<app-inputtype2-component>Label-Stirng 2</app-inputtype2-component>
</form>
```

inputtype1.component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inputtype1',
  templateUrl: './inputtype1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inputtype1.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]
})

export class Inputtype1Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() stamp = '';
  // @ts-ignore
  @ViewChild(FormControlName) control;

  constructor(public fgd: FormGroupDirective, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

inputtype1.component.html :

```
<label class="label">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</label>
<input type="text" id="{{stamp}}" class="input" formControlName="{{stamp}}"/>
<app-errors *ngIf="control?.invalid" [errors]="control.errors"></app-errors>
```

Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: did you try ControlValueAccessor  ?

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji I have already looked into ControlValueAccessor and while i think it provides an opportunity for better optimizing some aspects (and it's possible to inject ngcontrol), using it would require us to reimplement the functionality already present inide angular. Most of our custom input components are just one native <input> element wrapped inside other tags for layout and errors. Still we would have to rewrite CheckboxControlValueAccessor and the others with basically the same functionality or is there a way to reuse the existing ValueAccessors?